# WoW addon to figure out most profitable jewelcrafting route

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I currently have 525 jewelcrafting and 525 leather working. I'm wondering if there is a solid add-on that would be able to perhaps scan the auction house to understand the economy better on my particular server, and then give me a list of the most profitable things to cut/craft? Any tips are welcome for automating the profit route.

Comment: It's been a while since i played wow, but i used to work with Auctioneer, after a few days of scanning the prices you get will be give or take correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lyrion said, Auctioneer is probably the most popular auction house tool for gathering information.  But I have found that no one add-on always gives you everything you need.  You may want to check out some other auction/crafting mods, such as Auctionator and TradeSkillMaster, which can help you to optimize your crafting.  Regardless of the convenience of the tools you use, a big part of crafting and playing the market will be the manual tasks of paying attention and recognizing demand.